# Spring boot keycloak integration comes in role null in @preauthorize

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak

I am trying to perform **authorization** operations using **keycloak**.

My security config class works fine, I successfully create authentication via **jwt** token and perform the necessary role mapping. This is clearly visible through the security context holder.

[image]

I'm using the preauthorize annotation, because the authorities are null in it, authorization is not provided, I get 403.

[image]

I still don't understand how it is possible, can you help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a long struggle, I found the solution.

```
@Override
protected KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider() {
    return new KeycloakAuthenticationProvider() {

        @Override
        public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
            KeycloakAuthenticationToken token = (KeycloakAuthenticationToken) authentication;
            List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<>();

            for (String role : ((KeycloakPrincipal) token.getPrincipal()).getKeycloakSecurityContext().getToken().getRealmAccess().getRoles()) {
                grantedAuthorities.add(new KeycloakRole(role));
            }

            return new KeycloakAuthenticationToken(token.getAccount(), token.isInteractive(), new SimpleAuthorityMapper().mapAuthorities(grantedAuthorities));
        }

    };
}
```

We can reach the solution by setting the roles into KeycloakAuthenticationToken with the following method in the Security config class.